# Keras: How to calculate total memory required for model.fit()

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Every time I hit the OOM headboard it hangs and I'm forced to restart the kernel in Spyder.

For a 2dLocallyConnected network, how can I calculate the memory required for various batch sizes?

Edit* Code wasn't included because I was hoping for a general answer.  Something along the lines of # of parameters * 4 bits + size of batch * some constant.

Here is an example network:

```
model = Sequential([
LocallyConnected2D(100, kernel_size=(10, 20), strides=1, padding='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(10, 90, 1)),
 Flatten(),

Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Please include some code in your question, in its current form its not clear what the network structure is.